# TableLayoutPanel - not aligning custom control columns to center on form resize

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm using tablelayoutpanel for some dynamically created control.
But on resize of form (maximize), the columns do not align properly.

Given in image[image]

Here is my code

```
  TableLayoutPanel panelItems = new TableLayoutPanel();
                            panelItems.ColumnStyles.Clear();
                            panelItems.Padding = new Padding(0,0,0,100);
                            panelItems.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                            panelItems.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
                            panelItems.Tag = item.id;   
                            panelItems.ColumnCount = 3;
                            panelItems.RowCount = 2;
                            panelItems.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
                            this.Controls.Add(panelItems);


//Get items
 if (categoryItemProducts.Any())
                            {
                                foreach (var product in categoryItemProducts)
                                {
                                    //Create new control
                                    ctrItem productItem = new ctrItem(product.id);
                                    productItem.BackColor = Color.Brown;
                                    //productItem.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
                                    productItem.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
                                    //Add it to tablelayout
                                    panelItems.Controls.Add(productItem);
                                }
                            }
                            panelItems.AutoScroll = false;
                            panelItems.Visible = false;
                            panelItems.AutoSize = true;
```

Please help me.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap.css? in your project?

Comment: This is a windows forms project.

Comment: The TLP has 3 columns but only 1 column style.  Doing this with the designer and then looking at the code in generates in InitializeComponent() is an easy way to get this right.